# generator function for matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, generator

I'm trying to generate data for a matplotlib animation.
I have a data_gen function for matplotlib's "animation.FuncAnimation" function that is called like this:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=data_gen, init_func=init, interval=10, blit=True)
```

My code has this form:

```
def func(a):
    a += 1
    return a

b = 0

def data_gen():
    global b
    c = func(b)
    b = c
    yield c
```

Unfortunately, this does not do what I want!  For example,

```
print(data_gen().__next__())
print(data_gen().__next__())
print(data_gen().__next__())

for k in data_gen():
    print(k)
```

... produces this output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I was expecting that the for loop would run forever, but it does not.  (It stops at 4.)

The behavior I need is:

> (1) set initial value for b
>
> (2) update b each time the generator runs

All suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `data_gen()` in sets up a *new* generator, you just need to keep using the *same* generator object.  There is also no reason do explicitly maintain a global state, that is what the generator does for you:

```
def data_gen(init_val):
    b = init_val
    while True:
        b += 1
        yield b

gen = data_gen(3)
print next(gen)
print 'starting loop'
for j in gen:
    print j
    if j > 50:
        print "don't want to run forever, breaking"
        break
```

Comment: still wont work since there is no loop in the generator. it will only yield once.

Comment: @M4rtini Your right, got distracted by the other problems and confused by the global state....

Comment: @tcaswell This is very helpful; however, including arguments to data_gen does not seem to work in the animation.FuncAnimation function call.  I will ask another question if I can narrow down the source of the trouble.  Thanks again.

Comment: You should be calling it like `FuncAnimation(..., frames=gen_data(3),...)`.  What errors does it give you?

Comment: @tcaswell Well... this is getting quite far away from the original question, but the error is: TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()   This occurs in matplotlib\animation.py "self.save_count = len(frames)"

Comment: ah, I just fixed that bug.... bug: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1769 PR: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2634  and it hasn't been merged into master yet...

Comment: @tcaswell  Wow!  I can't believe I ran into a bug that's not my fault.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When I add an infinite loop into `data_gen` like this:

```
b=0
def data_gen():
    global b
    while True:
        b+=1
        yield b
```

I get (I use python 3.3, but the result should be the same for 2.x)

```
next(data_gen())
> 1
next(data_gen())
>2
next(data_gen())
>3

list(zip(range(10), data_gen()))
> [(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 9), (6, 10), (7, 11), (8, 12), (9, 13)]
```

And finally if I do

```
for i in data_gen():
    print(i)
```

the code goes on and on printing numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(a):
    a += 1
    return a

b = 0

def data_gen():
    global b
    while 1:
          c = func(b)
          b = c
          yield c

>>> gen.next()
    1
>>> gen.next()
    2
>>> gen.next()
    3
>>> gen.next()
    4
>>> gen.next()
    5
```