# Matplotlib - Slider Animation Freezes

Tags: matplotlib, animation, freeze

I made a simple animation slider for viewing slices of 3D images. I adapted it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325447/animated-interactive-plot-using-matplotlib) post. One small problem though, after a little sliding around it always freezes up. After some fiddling around I realised that the freeze stops from happening if I add a print statement to my update method. So I figured that it has something to do with threads getting in each others way (I'm no expert, just guessing) so instead of an ugly print statement I tried including a sleep in its place. But t doesn't work! The only thing that stops it from freezing is a print statement. Why might this be?

```
def animate(img, cmap='viridis', clim=None):
    fig, _ = plt.subplots()
    index = 0
    max_index = len(img)

    plot = plt.imshow(img[index])
    plt.set_cmap(cmap)
    if clim is not None: plt.clim(clim[0], clim[1])

    ax = plt.axes([0.25, .03, 0.50, 0.02])
    slider = Slider(ax, "Index", 0, (max_index - 1), valinit=index, valfmt='%d')

    def update(i):
        print("Hello World!")  # Delay to stop freeze. Only thing that seems to work, not even sleep works.
        i = int(slider.val)
        plot.set_data(img[i])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    slider.on_changed(update)

    plt.show()
```

EDIT: After some further investigation I noticed that if the image is deeper (more slices) even the print statement is not sufficient. Because of this I am starting to believe that it has something to do with that the update method is called too many times in a short time span.

EDIT 2: Calling the function from the python console with animate([np.random.rand(300,300) for _ in range(20)], clim=[0,1]) produces the error on my machine. You need to swipe the slider back and forth rapidly a little while.

EDIT 3: I am using TkAgg version 3.1.2

Comment: When calling your function with `animate([np.random.rand(30,30) for _ in range(20)], clim=[0,1])` I do not observe any strange behaviour. Can you make sure to have a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest See my latest edit. Changing that to `animate([np.random.rand(300,300) for _ in range(20)], clim=[0,1]) ` reproduces the error.

Comment: Mhh, not for me. Even if using `rand(3000,3000)` the silder still works, though of course there is a little latency when moving it fast.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I notice now that the issue only occurs if I run it from the python console. Have any idea why?

Comment: No. Maybe you want to add `print(plt.get_backend(), matplotlib.__version__)` and report about the backend/version in the cases you are considering.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am using TkAgg version 3.1.2. calling `plt.get_backend(), matplotlib.__version__` (without printing) also seems to resolve the issue.