# Changing the image of a matplotlib button widget

Tags: python, image, button, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib button widget with an image.  After clicking the button, I want to change the image to something else.  I tried this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

FIGURE = plt.figure()
ICON_PLAY = mpimg.imread('./ui/images/play.png')
ICON_PAUSE = mpimg.imread('./ui/images/pause.png')

def play(event):
    print "Starting"
    start_button.image = ICON_PAUSE

start_button = Button(plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]), '', image=ICON_PLAY)
start_button.on_clicked(play)
plt.show()
```

The event handler is called, but the image is not changed.  Does someone know how to change the image of a matplotlib button widget after construction?

Comment: Maybe you don't actually need images, but rather use some arrows or so as labels, `Button(ax, label=ur'$\u25B6$')`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989063/4124317).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image of a `matplotlib.widget.Button` is an `imshow` plot in the axes of the button. Hence you may get the existing image from the axes via `button_axes.images[0]` and set new data on it, `button_axes.images[0].set_data(ICON_PAUSE)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure()
ICON_PLAY =  plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySW6o.png')
ICON_PAUSE = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTa3H.png")

def play(event):
    button_axes.images[0].set_data(ICON_PAUSE)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

button_axes = plt.axes([0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4])
start_button = Button(button_axes, '', image=ICON_PLAY)
start_button.on_clicked(play)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!