# Playback error results when using an animation player that subclasses FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Python 3.9, Mac OS 11.6.1

I'm implementing the animation example posted a few years ago at [Managing dynamic plotting in matplotlib Animation module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985966/managing-dynamic-plotting-in-matplotlib-animation-module/44989063#44989063), which incorporates a nice playback console. However when the animation reaches its conclusion, pressing the play button again will throw an out-of-bounds index error. How can I modify the code, which I've included below for the sake of completeness, so that nothing happens when the play button is pressed at the end of the animation, or, better yet, the animation starts again from the beginning.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
import matplotlib.widgets

class Player(FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self, fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None,
                 save_count=None, mini=0, maxi=100, pos=(0.125, 0.92), **kwargs):
        self.i = 0
        self.min=mini
        self.max=maxi
        self.runs = True
        self.forwards = True
        self.fig = fig
        self.func = func
        self.setup(pos)
        FuncAnimation.__init__(self,self.fig, self.func, frames=self.play(), 
                                           init_func=init_func, fargs=fargs,
                                           save_count=save_count, **kwargs )    

    def play(self):
        while self.runs:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
            if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
                yield self.i
            else:
                self.stop()
                yield self.i

    def start(self):
        self.runs=True
        self.event_source.start()

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.runs = False
        self.event_source.stop()

    def forward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.start()
    def backward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.start()
    def oneforward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.onestep()
    def onebackward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.onestep()

    def onestep(self):
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
        elif self.i == self.min and self.forwards:
            self.i+=1
        elif self.i == self.max and not self.forwards:
            self.i-=1
        self.func(self.i)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def setup(self, pos):
        playerax = self.fig.add_axes([pos[0],pos[1], 0.22, 0.04])
        divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(playerax)
        bax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        sax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        ofax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.05)
        self.button_oneback = matplotlib.widgets.Button(playerax, label=u'$\u29CF$')
        self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(bax, label=u'$\u25C0$')
        self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(sax, label=u'$\u25A0$')
        self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax, label=u'$\u25B6$')
        self.button_oneforward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ofax, label=u'$\u29D0$')
        self.button_oneback.on_clicked(self.onebackward)
        self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
        self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
        self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)
        self.button_oneforward.on_clicked(self.oneforward)

### using this class is as easy as using FuncAnimation:            

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0,6*np.pi, num=100)
y = np.sin(x)

ax.plot(x,y)
point, = ax.plot([],[], marker="o", color="crimson", ms=15)

def update(i):
    point.set_data(x[i],y[i])

ani = Player(fig, update, maxi=len(y)-1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add an `if` condition to your `start` function to check if your `self.i` value reached `self.max`. If it does you can just reset your `self.i` value to zero and let the animation start again. Below id the code to do this:

```py
def start(self):
    if self.i==self.max:
        self.i=0
    self.runs=True
    self.event_source.start()
```