# How to prevent auto-start of animation created using the Player class that subclasses FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm using the Player class as found at [Managing dynamic plotting in matplotlib Animation module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985966/managing-dynamic-plotting-in-matplotlib-animation-module/44989063#44989063) to create an animation and can't figure out how to modify the initial values to prevent the animation from starting automatically. Below is the code for Player, along with a simple example, where I graph the unit circle and have arrows tracing out the unit circle as the frames advance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import mpl_toolkits
import matplotlib.widgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Player(FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self, fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, 
    fargs=None,save_count=None, mini=0, maxi=100, pos=(0.125, 0.92), **kwargs):
    self.i = 0
    self.min=mini
    self.max=maxi
    self.runs = True
    self.forwards = True

    self.fig = fig
    self.func = func
    self.setup(pos)
    FuncAnimation.__init__(self,self.fig, self.func, frames=self.play(),
                                       init_func=init_func, fargs=fargs,
                                       save_count=save_count,interval=500, **kwargs )


    def play(self):
        while self.runs:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
            if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
                yield self.i
            else:
                self.stop()
                yield self.i

    def start(self):
        if self.i==self.max:
            self.i=0
        self.runs=True
        self.event_source.start()

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.runs = False
        self.event_source.stop()

    def forward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.start()

    def backward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.start()

    def oneforward(self, event=None):
        if self.i==self.max:
            self.i=0
        self.forwards = True
        self.onestep()
    def onebackward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.onestep()

    def onestep(self):
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
        elif self.i == self.min and self.forwards:
            self.i+=1
        elif self.i == self.max and not self.forwards:
            self.i-=1
        self.func(self.i)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def setup(self, pos):
        playerax = self.fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.92, 0.22, 0.03])

        divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(playerax)
        bax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        sax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        ofax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.05)
        self.button_oneback = matplotlib.widgets.Button(playerax , label=u'$\u29CF$')
        self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(bax, label=u'$\u25C0$')
        self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(sax, label=u'$\u25A0$')
        self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax, label=u'$\u25B6$')
        self.button_oneforward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ofax, label=u'$\u29D0$')
        self.button_oneback.on_clicked(self.onebackward)
        self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
        self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
        self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)
        self.button_oneforward.on_clicked(self.oneforward)


######## EXAMPLE ##################
#######################################

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t=np.linspace(0,1, num=100)
unit_circle_x=np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
unit_circle_y=np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax.plot(unit_circle_x,unit_circle_y)
ax.set_xlim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax.set_ylim(-1.2,1.2)

# arrow tracing out unit circle
n=3
unit_vector_x=np.cos(2*np.pi*n*t)
unit_vector_y=np.sin(2*np.pi*n*t)


unit_circle_vector=ax.quiver(0, 0, unit_vector_x[0], unit_vector_y[0], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1,headwidth=10)
ax.set_aspect("equal")

def update(i):

    unit_circle_vector.set_UVC(unit_vector_x[i],unit_vector_y[i])
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$i= $'+str(i),rotation=0,labelpad=10)

ani = Player(fig, update, maxi=len(t)-1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initiate your `self.runs` variable to `False` and modify the `play` methods such that it yields the current position when `self.runs=False`:

```py
def play(self):
    while not self.runs:
        yield self.i
    while self.runs:
        self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            yield self.i
        else:
            self.stop()
            yield self.i
```

See full code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import mpl_toolkits
import matplotlib.widgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Player(FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self, fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, 
        fargs=None,save_count=None, mini=0, maxi=100, pos=(0.125, 0.92), **kwargs):
        self.i = 0
        self.min=mini
        self.max=maxi
        self.runs = False
        self.forwards = True

        self.fig = fig
        self.func = func
        self.setup(pos)
        FuncAnimation.__init__(self,self.fig, self.func, frames=self.play(),
                                           init_func=init_func, fargs=fargs,
                                           save_count=save_count,interval=500, **kwargs )

    def play(self):
        while not self.runs:
            yield self.i
        while self.runs:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
            if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
                yield self.i
            else:
                self.stop()
                yield self.i

    def start(self):
        if self.i==self.max:
            self.i=0
        self.runs=True
        self.event_source.start()

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.runs = False
        self.event_source.stop()

    def forward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.start()

    def backward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.start()

    def oneforward(self, event=None):
        if self.i==self.max:
            self.i=0
        self.forwards = True
        self.onestep()
    def onebackward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.onestep()

    def onestep(self):
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
        elif self.i == self.min and self.forwards:
            self.i+=1
        elif self.i == self.max and not self.forwards:
            self.i-=1
        self.func(self.i)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def setup(self, pos):
        playerax = self.fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.92, 0.22, 0.03])

        divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(playerax)
        bax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        sax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        ofax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.05)
        self.button_oneback = matplotlib.widgets.Button(playerax , label=u'$\u29CF$')
        self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(bax, label=u'$\u25C0$')
        self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(sax, label=u'$\u25A0$')
        self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax, label=u'$\u25B6$')
        self.button_oneforward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ofax, label=u'$\u29D0$')
        self.button_oneback.on_clicked(self.onebackward)
        self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
        self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
        self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)
        self.button_oneforward.on_clicked(self.oneforward)


######## EXAMPLE ##################
#######################################

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t=np.linspace(0,1, num=100)
unit_circle_x=np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
unit_circle_y=np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax.plot(unit_circle_x,unit_circle_y)
ax.set_xlim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax.set_ylim(-1.2,1.2)

# arrow tracing out unit circle
n=3
unit_vector_x=np.cos(2*np.pi*n*t)
unit_vector_y=np.sin(2*np.pi*n*t)


unit_circle_vector=ax.quiver(0, 0, unit_vector_x[0], unit_vector_y[0], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1,headwidth=10)
ax.set_aspect("equal")

def update(i):

    unit_circle_vector.set_UVC(unit_vector_x[i],unit_vector_y[i])
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$i= $'+str(i),rotation=0,labelpad=10)

ani = Player(fig, update, maxi=len(t)-1)

plt.show()
```

And here is the result:

[image]