# Animating a set of lines in a class

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, oop, matplotlib-animation

I have a class in which I used one of the codes in StackOverflow,
this link :[Managing dynamic plotting in matplotlib Animation module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985966/managing-dynamic-plotting-in-matplotlib-animation-module)

Now I want to edit this class and add some parameters to the class, for example data and add update function in a class, at the end I would like only call the class in another script and see the result.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
import matplotlib.widgets
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

file = "/Users/hadis/Documents/data_preparation/new_dataset/tracks_08.csv"
data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",", dtype=None)
path = "/Users/hadis/Desktop/project/5_Data/08_background.png"



class visualizer(FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self,fig, data,frames=None, 
    init_func=None, fargs=None,
             save_count=None,background_path=None, mini=0, 
             maxi=100, pos= (0.75, 0.04), **kwargs):

    self.i = 0
    self.min=mini
    self.max=maxi
    self.data = data
    self.background_path = background_path
    self.runs = True
    self.forwards = True
    self.fig = fig
    self.ax = self.fig.gca()
    plt.xlabel("X-Position [m]", fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel("Y-Position [m]", fontsize=12)

    img = plt.imread(self.background_path)
   
    plt.imshow(img,extent=[0,1170,-780,0])
    number = self.background_path.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0] 
    plt.title("Track " + number)

    self.setup(pos)
    if fig is None:
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
    else:
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = self.fig.gca()

    self.lines = []
    for i in range(3):
        self.line, = plt.plot([], [])
        self.lines.append(self.line)

    #self.func = update


    FuncAnimation.__init__(self,self.fig, self.update, frames=self.play(), 
                                       init_func=init_func, fargs=fargs,
                                       save_count=save_count, **kwargs )    


def play(self):
    while self.runs:
        self.i = self.i+self.forwards - (not self.forwards)
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            yield self.i
        else:
            self.stop()
            yield self.i

def start(self):
    self.runs=True
    self.event_source.start()

def stop(self, event=None):
    self.runs = False
    self.event_source.stop()

def forward(self, event=None):
    self.forwards = True
    self.start()

def backward(self, event=None):
    self.forwards = False
    self.start()

def setup(self,pos):
    playerax = self.fig.add_axes([pos[0],pos[1], 0.15, 0.05])
    divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(playerax)
    
    sax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.06)
    fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.06)
  
    self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(playerax, label=u'$\u25C0$')
    self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(sax, label=u'$\u25A0$')
    self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax,label=u'$\u25B6$')
    
   
    self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
    self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
    self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)
    self.button_forward.label.set_fontsize(15)
    self.button_back.label.set_fontsize(15)
    self.button_stop.label.set_fontsize(14)
    self.ax.set_xticklabels([0,20,40,60,80,100,120])
    self.ax.set_yticklabels([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
    self.ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
    self.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
    self.ax.set_xlim(0,1170)
    self.ax.set_ylim(-780,0)

def set_data(self,data):
    groups = itertools.groupby(self.data, key=lambda x: x[0])
    lst = [[[item[2], item[3]] for item in group] for _, group in groups]

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in self.data:
        d[i[0]].append((i[1]))
        self.start_frames = [i[0] for i in d.values()]

    # For visualisation we should convert positions from meter to pixel 
    self.new_list = [[[z/(0.008146*12) for z in y] for y in x] for x in lst]

    return self.new_list, self.start_frames
 
def update(self,frame):
    for i in range(len(self.new_list)):
        if frame > self.start_frames[i] and frame < self.start_frames[i] + len(self.new_list[i]):
            x = [self.new_list[i][j-self.start_frames[i]][0] for j in range(max(self.start_frames[i],frame-9), frame+1)]
            y = [self.new_list[i][j-self.start_frames[i]][1] for j in range(max(self.start_frames[i],frame-9), frame+1)]
            self.lines[i].set_data(x, y)
    
        else:
            self.lines[i].set_data([], [])

    return self.lines




fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ani = visualizer(fig,data,background_path= 
path,maxi=10000,interval=40,blit= False)
plt.show()
```

In the end, it gives me an empty figure, with no animation. can anyone give me advise on how can I restructure my code? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could create a class for that, you gonna have to modify your code this way:

edit: we added buttons

your class:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
import matplotlib.widgets
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

class Visualizer:
    def __init__(self, data, background_path, mini=0, maxi=10000, interval=40, blit=False):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.data = data
        self.background_path = background_path
        self.mini = mini
        self.maxi = maxi
        self.interval = interval
        self.blit = blit
        self.paused = False

        self.new_list, self.start_frames = self.set_data(self.data)

        self.lines = []
        for i in range(3):
            line, = self.ax.plot([], [])
            self.lines.append(line)

        self.setup((0.75, 0.04))

        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, frames=range(self.mini, self.maxi), 
                                 init_func=self.init, interval=self.interval, blit=self.blit)

        self.add_buttons()

    # ... (other methods remain unchanged) ...

    def add_buttons(self):
        ax_play = plt.axes([0.7, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
        ax_stop = plt.axes([0.81, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
        ax_reset = plt.axes([0.92, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])

        self.button_play = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ax_play, 'Play')
        self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ax_stop, 'Stop')
        self.button_reset = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ax_reset, 'Reset')

        self.button_play.on_clicked(self.play)
        self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
        self.button_reset.on_clicked(self.reset)

    def play(self, event):
        if self.paused:
            self.ani.event_source.start()
            self.paused = False

    def stop(self, event):
        if not self.paused:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
            self.paused = True

    def reset(self, event):
        self.ani.frame_seq = self.ani.new_frame_seq()
        self.ani.event_source.start()
        self.paused = False

    def show(self):
        plt.show()
```

then if you want to use it in your script:

```
file = "/Users/hadis/Documents/data_preparation/new_dataset/tracks_08.csv"
data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",", dtype=None)
path = "/Users/hadis/Desktop/project/5_Data/08_background.png"

vis = Visualizer(data=data, background_path=path, mini=0, maxi=10000, interval=40, blit=False)

vis.show()
```

Comment: @Saxthoowl is it possible to add buttons?

Comment: Yes, I modified my answer